# Should we stay opted-in for Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fun, winterbash

It's that time of year again!

This year's event will run from **December 19th** to **January 8th**.  More information on this and individual hat-earning progress will eventually be posted [here](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/).

Once again, this is an opt-out year, meaning that we don't have to do anything if the community agrees on participating.  But, we get new users every year, so everyone should be informed.  Either way, the new dates are useful since they do change each year.

Let's all celebrate another successful year of Code Review and look forward to having an even more successful one!

[image]

Comment: Winter is coming.

Answer (score 29):

It's not simply tradition, it's part of the community's culture. We're one of the few SE sites known for actually liking *fun*™. Let's keep it that way. Let the Winterbash games commence!

May the odds be ever in your favor.

Comment: Not to mention, last year's champion was our own Quill!

Comment: What is this "fun" of which you speak? This concept is unfamiliar to me. Please define in detail, and explain precisely why it is desirable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin it's this wonderful thing that releases endorphins into the blood stream. It helps keep depression at bay during the cold, dark, winter months.

Comment: @RubberDuck: if you wish to participate in this "fun", you may submit a form C-17b (in triplicate) and the committee will determine the percentage of time that may be devoted to this activity. The committee meets quarterly, so please allow 3 to 6 months for a decision. Enclose a SASE if you wish to be notified directly of the committee's decision.

Comment: But Jerry! I have TPS reports to finish for the Bobs!

Comment: @RubberDuck: And be sure to use the new cover sheets!

Answer (score 21):

## WEAR TEH HATZ!

I think we should participate, it is kind of a tradition.

Answer (score 7):

Playing Devil's Advocate here.  We shouldn't wear the hats because it reduces the quality of contributions to the site, encourages gaming activity, and generally increases fun and reduces seriousness on the site.

Comment: I'm a little surprised by the number of upvotes this got. I would love to hear from the folks who don't want to participate in the festivities. It's your site too and we'd like to understand your point of view.

Comment: @RubberDuck I upvoted because, from recollection, some of the hats were _just unconstructive_, take [this meta question (10k required)](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6326). If it didn't encourage bad contributions to the site, and hats were more like [hat trick](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6344) then I'd be all for it.

Comment: ... yeah @Peilonrayz I see where you're coming from with that. That was a bad choice for a hat. However, our mods handled the situation perfectly. No harm was actually done.

Comment: @Peilonrayz FYI that specific episode led to [this post on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271140/197901)

Comment: I downvoted this for no better reason then that it was fun to do so.

Comment: Should we also remove reputation because it encourages gaming activity?

Comment: @RubberDuck As someone who doesn't like WinterBash, I agree with Hosch's views. It is good for the site and does promote a fun environment. I mean, more than half of my questions on this site were made for fun! So, let others have fun, while I get to be the grumpy oldie in the corner. As long as I'm not forced to participate on it, I'm totally fine.