# Should we bring back the fun?

Tags: discussion, fun

Since we've not had any [fun](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun) in a little while, I thought maybe it'd be a good idea to 'bring back' the fun. In the past this has been in the form of Winterbash, community challenges, best of Code Reviews, and a couple other things.

I'm unsure what we as a community want to do, and so I think it'd be nice to have a little poll of things we could do together. I've included some things that we have done in the past in the poll by default, but that doesn't mean that we can't have more things to do. Or that we even have to do those things.

Since this post is just a poll, the core isn't to discuss all the ins and outs of the ways we want to have fun.

- Say we want to play some Factorio together we could continue the discussion in chat and come to a conclusion of how to play there.
- Say we want to continue community challenges, we should have a meta discussion on what they should be. Currently there a weird mix of winning and slowly becoming bigger and bigger challenges. So a refresh of these could be good.

---

How would we all like to have fun?

Answer (score 26):

## Zombie Hunting Season

The [old memes](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510) pretty much all happened during the Great Revival, during which we equated unanswered questions with zombies, and votes/answers with ammunition.

The site currently has ~10% unanswered questions, which means a population of ~5K zombies; how about reopening zombie-hunting season? Sportive reviewing for all!

[image: Have you killed a ZOMBIE lately?]

The idea being, of course, to foster answering activity, by encouraging everyone to pick a daily zombie and slay it - and encouraging voting activity too.

Of course this entails taking a snapshot of the data *before* the launch, then publish weekly updates, charts, leaderboards - upping meta-site activity as well!

Comment: So, I've re-submitted the ad on the [2018 community ads meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8708/23788), to help promote this.

Comment: Loving this. Maybe it could be executed similarly as your [Call of Duty](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/999/call-of-duty-were-on-a-mission) post.

Comment: @janos I'm thinking we need a number of SEDE queries, exports to CSV, and a PowerBI dashboard =)

Comment: I think we should set a goal for such an event, such as @janos stated in his (now deleted) answer. It's not realistic to get rid of *all* the zombies, but having a goal to reduce unanswered questions % to 9 would be nice.

Answer (score 12):

## Community challenges

These started off as weekly challenges, and has slowly expanded to three monthly challenges. These can be found under the [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) tag.

We should probably refresh what these are. As they've been forever changing.

Comment: FYI: I'm working on a flexible game server that will support several different turn-based games. Get your Sockets and WebSockets ready and we can have AI battles!

Comment: @SimonForsberg That's pretty cool, it'd be cool to see that in the wild!

Comment: A flexible online game server can be found here: https://github.com/Zomis/Server2 . Documentation might still be lacking a bit, but most of it is there. See README.md and MESSAGING.md for starters.

Answer (score 9):

## Secret Santa

[This happened once](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6263), and had large community support. And an [ex-community manager](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6350#comment14544_6391) followed the fun.

It was actually really fun, and made me appreciate the community a lot. I think we should bring these back. I'd be happy to look into setting up future ones too.

Comment: If I might say, it was pretty easy to organize and it was great fun. I still have my Cloud Storage eh eh

Answer (score 8):

## IRL Meetup

I'm not sure if we have ever successfully organised one, but I know [in the past](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=meetup&room=8595) we have talked about doing one.

I think it'd be unreasonable to get *everyone* together. But a couple of us that live in the same country or continent could try to meet up.

Comment: In the alternative, a Hangout/Skype/whatever live meet could also work, most of the regulars live too far apart to meet up in person.

Comment: I know for a fact that A&M did conduct an IRL meetup in Europe. I can try dig out their meta post on the matter if anyone's interested

Comment: This is an awesome idea! :D

Answer (score 7):

## Reputation Races

[Back in the days](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=on%20the%20wall&Room=8595&page=15&pagesize=50&sort=newest), a Mug and a Simon were racing to... 20k? 10k? Some k. reputation, it is a fun thing to do together with someone else and leads to more activity and answers. It's a win-win even if you don't win the race.

One can even use [our favorite bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=quarter&user=125580&room=) to keep track of the rating differences.

Comment: I've always wondered, how do you set this up? Say I want to race another member, what would I need to do?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Either just let me know, or give me a pull-request adding a line here: https://github.com/Zomis/Duga/blob/develop/grails-app/services/net/zomis/duga/DugaFileConfig.groovy#L15

Comment: That is: `ratingdiff;(chat room id);(userid 1),(userid 2);(site)`

Comment: "Back in the days", officially there are still 2 ([1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43679113#43679113) [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43679117#43679117)) races running. Quite slowly...

Answer (score 7):

## Playing our home-made games!

There are several games that are being developed by the community, mainly in the [Coding Projects](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven) chat room. We should [have some events every now and then](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8851/31562) to play these games. Some of us will also stream this on Twitch.

The available games to play are:

- Connect Four
- The Royal Game of Ur
- Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe
- Cardshifter
- Checkers
- Minesweeper Flags
- and possibly more...

The first event was held on [Saturday, May 12, at 15:00 UTC](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=saturday+15+UTC) in [Coding Projects chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven).

Answer (score 6):

## Best of Code Review

These happen once a year, normally in January. And we give bounties to some of the best answers and questions in the year. These can be found under the [best-of](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) tag.

Comment: IME it gets hard to track/remember Q1, Q2 and even Q3 posts in a yearly setup. I've seen other sites do something similar, but on a quarterly basis. Maybe that would be a better thing?

Answer (score 5):

## Factorio Server

It may come to a surprise to some but some of us are really mad about Factorio. We have [150 messages of chat history with the word 'factorio'](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Factorio&Room=8595&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest). Maybe some of us have played too much of it (no judging I have 2k hours in DotA 2):

> @rolfl Couldn't have described it better myself. Although my time counter is "only" 917 hours. - [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41914504#41914504)

Should we try setting up a Code Review Factorio server?

Comment: Not counting [a lot more Factorio talk](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=Factorio&room=16134) in our Coding Projects & [Factorio Heaven room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven) =)

Comment: @Phrancis Oh damn, that place is a thing... :O #AddNewRoomToFavourites

Answer (score 4):

## Reviews

We just love reviewing here! And had a ['14 review of the site](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3822), along with [a review of the memes we've made](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510).

I think these can help keep our users voice problems they think the site has. I think we all have a couple of concerns with the site at the moment. But I've not seen a central place to discuss these views.

Answer (score 3):

## No!

We should **not** bring back the fun.  Fun is dangerous, immoral and antithetical to writing high quality code.  What we really ought to do instead is write accounting software in COBOL.

> Yes, I'm joking. :)

Answer (score -2):

## Winterbash

We've always included ourselves in Winterbash. It's a bit of a ritual. And a couple of years back a few of us got quite far in it. We've asked about doing it every year since 2013, except this year. [2013](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1067), [2014](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3755), [2015](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6260) and [2016](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7072).

Comment: We have participated in 2017 as well though, we just didn't make a meta post about it.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I may have not been clear, but I said that in the above post, :)

Comment: Kind of the wrong time of year for Winterbash...

Comment: IMO CR should be de-facto opting into the year-end hat-fest - 2017 we didn't ask, because we knew what the answer was going to be. Everybody loves hats!....right? (and if you don't, then you can hate hats on your own, no need to spoil the fun for everyone else on the site)

Comment: @RubberDuck I know how Winterbash works and when it happens. Just like I've added an answer for 'best of CR', I added Winterbash so we know if we want to do it.

Comment: We've got 9 months till the next bash.... Let's focus on other kinds of fun in the meantime.

Comment: @RubberDuck I don't think you understand the point of this post. It's not about _right now_. We're not going to do secret santa, or best of CR for another year either. It's about things we want to do _this_ and _future_ years.

Comment: Then please clarify the *question*.

Comment: @RubberDuck I don't see how it's not clear. I've only said that I want to know ways we want to have fun. I never said ways we want to have fun today, this week or this month...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Aren't all sites by default opted in nowadays?

Comment: @Mast IIRC [since 2016 that's been the case](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7072)