# Playing our home-made games!

Tags: discussion, fun

As developers we know that it's not always easy to get people to *play* the games that we make.
We also know that it's not always easy to find motivation to *work* on the games you want to make.

This is why, once every other Saturday at 15:00 UTC, we will hold an event for playing home-made games.

We have had such an event once already, on Saturday May 12th 15:00 UTC, and we considered it a success. Games that were played then was: [Cardshifter, The Royal Game of Ur, Tic-Tac-Toe Ultimate, Checkers, Minesweeper Flags, and Connect Four](http://bit.ly/codereview-games).
People participating in the event included, among others, @Phrancis @EthanBierlein @DainIronfootIII and myself.
Some of us were streaming on Twitch and personally I had a record of 6 viewers (I don't have many followers - yet, still quite new to streaming).

If you are developing a game that you would like us to play, you may suggest it in [Coding Projects chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven).

**[See the next event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven?tab=schedule) and join us for it in [Coding Projects chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16134/coding-projects-and-factorio-heaven)**

Comment: So it's up to game developpers to make their game available online? Or will there be some sort of mutualized hosting?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger It's currently up to everyone to make their game available online (or downloadable or runnable somehow). If there is need for hosting let me know and I *might* be able to solve this - but I can't promise anything.

Comment: Is there an option to make these activities be available to people with already conflicting bi-weekly activities? Assuming this is going to be a bi-weekly thing

Comment: @Peilonrayz Suggest a time and we might have another event, depending on who else can play at that time! You can also hop into the chatroom at any time and ask if someone wants to play one of the home-made games. We tend to play especially Checkers and Royal Game of Ur every now and then.

Comment: I get a 403 Forbidden when trying to reach games.zomis.net :(

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Whoops, I will look into that before the event starts.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8 - Works now!

Comment: @mdfst13 Updated the post. It will automatically be removed from the sidebar sometime.

Comment: Great initiative!